# I am getting an error on the 'start' in the (start + finish) at the bottom

Tags: java

I am getting an error on the 'start' in the (start + finish) at the bottom. The only way to fix it is to add "int start = inputFn.nextInt();" below ' Scanner inputFn = new Scanner(System.in);' but that screws it all up. I was able to fix it before but I forgot how I did it. Please help.

```
public static void main(String eth[]){

System.out.println("Please Enter An Integer:");
Scanner inputFn = new Scanner(System.in);


if (inputFn.hasNextInt()){
}else{
int start = inputFn.nextInt();
System.out.print("Play By The Rules And Enter An Integer");

}

System.out.println("Please Enter An Integer:");
Scanner inputSn = new Scanner(System.in);
int finish = inputSn.nextInt();

int answer = (start + finish);
System.out.println(answer);


}
}
```

Comment: **Be specific.** What error are you getting?

Comment: You need to declare the variable (`start` in your case) outside of the else, because it is only visible inside the declared scope. Alternatively you can put all of the second read into the else.

Comment: You're declaring the `start` variable in a condition-scope and are trying to call it at method-scope. This isn't possible. Better indentation of your code would better show this as being the problem you're having.

Comment: learn to format your code in a sane manner, you can only expect the same amount of effort you put into asking the question from someone helping, right that that is not much ...

Answer (score 0):

The if

```
if (inputFn.hasNextInt()){
}else{
  int start = inputFn.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Play By The Rules And Enter An Integer");
}
```

is kind of backwards. You are reading the integer only if there ISN'T one. And you are defining the start variable inside the if block which is why you are getting the error.

Something more like

```
int start = 0;
if (inputFn.hasNextInt()){
  start = inputFn.nextInt();
}else{
  System.out.print("Play By The Rules And Enter An Integer");
}
```

would seem better.

Comment: That did help. But it still doesn't get away that start error all the way at the bottom

Comment: @EthanCotler, did you put the int start definition outside the if block, and if you did, what specifically is the error

Comment: if I put "int start = inputFn.nextInt();" " below "Scanner inputFn = new Scanner(System.in);" it fixes the problem except adds an extra line in the console for user input, and I don't want that.

Comment: You need to do `int start;`  before the if, then inside the if `start = inputFn.nextInt();`, as in the example code I wrote.

Comment: I added =0 to the answer, otherwise you get a "variable not initialized" error.

Comment: @eckes, thank you. That is what I get for typing without compiling.